# Different set of popups for a different tab

Tags: apache-flex, tabs, popup

Suppose, I have a tabbed application. Can I make Popup window to appear in a given tab only? So, if I change a tab, the related popup(-s) hides. So far, I haven't found any solution for this. So any idea would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to handle different sets of popups by yourself : Flex can only add and remove given popups which will be displayed at the topmost level of your app.

EDIT : Here's a little sample.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- containers\navigators\TNSimple.mxml -->
<s:Application
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    creationComplete="onCreationComplete()"
    >
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            import mx.managers.PopUpManager;
            import spark.components.TitleWindow;
            import mx.events.IndexChangedEvent;

            private var popups:Array = [];

            private function onCreationComplete():void
            {
                popups = [[],[],[]];
            }

            private function createPopup():void
            {
                var foo:TitleWindow = new TitleWindow();

                PopUpManager.addPopUp(foo, this);

                PopUpManager.centerPopUp(foo);

                popups[nav.selectedIndex].push(foo);
            }

            private function onTabChange(event:IndexChangedEvent):void
            {
                var i:int;

                var oldArray:Array = popups[event.oldIndex];
                for (i = 0; i < oldArray.length; i++) {
                    PopUpManager.removePopUp(oldArray[i]);
                }

                var newArray:Array = popups[event.newIndex];
                for (i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
                    PopUpManager.addPopUp(newArray[i], this);
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <mx:TabNavigator id="nav" borderStyle="solid" x="50" y="50" change="onTabChange(event)">
        <mx:VBox label="Accounts" 
            width="300" 
            height="150">
            <mx:Button label="pop" click="createPopup()"/>
        </mx:VBox>

        <mx:VBox label="Stocks" 
            width="300" 
            height="150">
            <mx:Button label="pop" click="createPopup()"/>
        </mx:VBox>

        <mx:VBox label="Futures" 
            width="300" 
            height="150">
            <mx:Button label="pop" click="createPopup()"/>
        </mx:VBox>   
    </mx:TabNavigator>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: You could have, for instance, an array of arrays, and each of them would contain the popups for a specific tab. The thing is, of course, to maintain the indices synchronized with your tabs indices. See ?

Comment: Well, the basic functionality I already have. My popups already stored in a needed tab. But the problem is that PopupManager is a common thing for all the tabs .. and when I open popup and switch the tab - the popup still remains visible.

Comment: So you have to listen to your tab manager component, and when it changes the visible tab, change the visible popups.

Comment: So, there's no way to hide them? I only should use "removePopup()"?

Comment: Thanks a lot for a sample, is there any chance that after I call 'PopUpManager.removePopUp', the data in popup would not be cleared? That's the main trouble, cause each popup loads a lot of data after opening .. and loading and deleting it would not be the best solution :(

Comment: They are not cleared or deleted, just removed from the display list. So they still exist, but are not visible (that's one of the many big improvements from ActionScript 3)